# Background music doesn't turn off or on when it is supposed to

Tags: android, service, media-player

I've got a service which plays background music in all of my activities, but doesn't turn off while onPause or onStop. I want my music to turn off while apps close or screen turn off, doesnt matter in which activity usesr currently is. 
The problem is this:
I have a service. In every activity I coded what to do onPause and onStop. It works fine, but service also stops when I switch to another activity.

Code:

```
public class MyService extends Service {


private final String TAG = null;
MediaPlayer player;

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.id);
    player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    player.setVolume(100, 100);




}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    player.start();
    return 1;
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TO DO
}

public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TO DO Auto-generated method
    return null;
}


protected void onStop() {
    player.pause();
}

public void onPause() {
    player.pause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You will have to stop the service in the onDestroy method of your main activity. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033400/my-background-music-service-in-android-app-keeps-on-playing-even-when-i-close-th/41033445#41033445)