# Constant background running process - even when app is not in use

Tags: android, android-studio, service, background, foreground-service

I am working with other contributors on an open-source project in which we have made an Android App. Whenever the app is opened we get a notification that the app is running in the background and even when the app session is terminated, the notification doesn't go away. [Here is the link for the project](https://github.com/StealthViper/WashKaro)

The app has a lot of classes which could be the reason but we are not able to narrow it down. Though we do think that it could be the `BluetoothService` activity which uses Bluetooth signals. The notification comes **as soon as the app is launched** and then just stays there.

```
public class BluetoothService extends Service {

private static final Long TIMEOUT = Long.valueOf(2000);
private Application bluetoothApplication = null;
private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "BluetoothServiceChannel";
private static final String TAG = "BluetoothService";
private BluetoothScanner bluetoothScanner = null;
private BluetoothAdvertiser bluetoothAdvertiser = null;

public static final String ADVERTISE_FAILED =
        "com.example.android.bluetoothadvertisements.advertising_failed";



@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    bluetoothApplication = getApplication();
    bluetoothAdvertiser = new BluetoothAdvertiser(bluetoothApplication.getApplicationContext(), BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter());
    bluetoothScanner = new BluetoothScanner(bluetoothApplication.getApplicationContext(), BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter());

}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}



private void sendFailureIntent(int errorCode) {
    Intent failureIntent = new Intent();
    failureIntent.setAction(ADVERTISE_FAILED);
    // failureIntent.putExtra(ADVERTISE_FAIL_EXTRA_CODE, errorCode);
    sendBroadcast(failureIntent);
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        this.CreateChannelIfNeeded();

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PhysicalDistancerActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);


    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .build();

    startForeground(6, notification);
    bluetoothAdvertiser.startAdvertising();
    bluetoothScanner.startScanning();
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void CreateChannelIfNeeded() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   //  Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // running = false;
   bluetoothAdvertiser.stopAdvertising();
    bluetoothScanner.stopScanning();
    stopForeground(true);
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

This could be a major reason for uninstallations when the app is released so any input will be really helpful.

Comment: Giving it a quick look, I can see that there is a service which keeps on running in the background. BluetoothService (under contactTracer\bluetooth). Check it out.

Comment: how do I make sure it closes with the app? I have tried to add the code in this link but it has no effect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033400/my-background-music-service-in-android-app-keeps-on-playing-even-when-i-close-th

Comment: This may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857120/what-is-the-proper-way-to-stop-a-service-running-as-foreground

Comment: Will check it out. One more thing, the notification comes as soon as the app is opened so does that help you narrow it down?